# Are Falun Gong members killed and their organs harvested?

Tags: medical-science, china

Documentaries like [Hard To Believe](http://www.hardtobelievemovie.com/) and [Human Harvest](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7ZmFLi0lgY) make the case that prisoners charged with being members of religious organisations not sanctioned by the Communist Party are killed for their organs.

[Organisations](http://www.stoporganharvesting.org/) wanting to raise awareness cite evidence such as very short waiting times compared to first-world countries, etc.

Comment: [They've upgraded to pigs now](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-36286128).

Comment: Utterly inconclusive but ...: Falun Gong members hold regular 'peaceful sit there' public events in NZ. In Hong Kong I was surprised to see  a very extensive street display of anti-communist Falun Gong literature. | In my 15 visits to China with > 6 months in country and visits "all over" I nowhere saw or heard of any Falun Gong activity. | Whatever.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: Following the suppression of Falun Gong in 1999, you are unlikely to have seen any public activity in P R China after around 2001.

Answer (score 11):

A 2007 investigation called 'Revised Report into Allegations of Organ Harvesting of Falun Gong Practitioners in China' by David Matas, the senior legal counsel of B'nai Brith Canada and David Kilgour retired member of Parliament for the southeastern area of Edmonton, Alberta found the allegation to be true.

> Based on our further research, we are reinforced in our original conclusion that the allegations are true. We believe that there has been and continues today to be large scale organ seizures from unwilling Falun Gong practitioners.
>    We have concluded that the government of China and its agencies in numerous parts of the country, in particular hospitals but also detention centres and 'people's courts', since 1999 have put to death a large but unknown number of Falun Gong prisoners of conscience. Their vital organs, including kidneys, livers, corneas and hearts, were seized involuntarily for sale at high prices, sometimes to foreigners, who normally face long waits for voluntary donations of such organs in their home countries. [Source: BLOODY HARVEST Revised Report into Allegations of Organ Harvesting of Falun Gong Practitioners in China](http://organharvestinvestigation.net/report0701/report20070131.htm#_Toc160145104)

Two other independent investigations also corroborate the above findings.

> A study by Kirk Allison, associate director of the program in human rights and medicine at the University of Minnesota, was undertaken before our report was released.  Though his study was released shortly after our own, on July 25, 2006, Dr. Allison had reached his conclusions earlier, before we released our report.  He too concluded that organ harvesting from Falun Gong practitioners was happening.
>
> The other investigation was undertaken by European Parliament Vice President Edward McMillan-Scott.  Unlike Dr. Allison and ourselves, Mr. McMillan-Scott was actually able to go to China on a fact finding mission on May 19-21, 2006.  There he interviewed two witnesses Cao Dong and Niu Jinping.  About his meeting with Cao Dong, Mr. McMillan‑Scott reports that he "enquired whether he was aware of any organ harvesting camps in China. He said he definitely knew of them and knew people who had been sent to them. He had seen the cadaver of one of his friends, a Falun Gong practitioner, with holes in his body where the organs had been removed." [Source: BLOODY HARVEST Revised Report into Allegations of Organ Harvesting of Falun Gong Practitioners in China](http://organharvestinvestigation.net/report0701/report20070131.htm#_Toc160145104)

According to [Ethan Guttman](https://www.thestar.com/life/2014/10/21/qa_author_and_analyst_ethan_gutmann_discusses_chinas_illegal_organ_trade.html), the numbers are estimated to be around 65,000 live harvests.

> The process of organ-harvesting works something like this: Prisoners are examined to determine the health of their organs and their blood type. Now they are a product, waiting on a shelf — or a lobster in a tank. As a witness pointed out to Gutmann, “China is different from other countries. In other countries, patients wait for organs. In China, organs wait for patients.” When the time comes, the prisoner is shot somewhere in the head. He loses consciousness, but is not dead (if all goes well). Then the doctor removes the relevant organs — and the prisoner is finished off. In the spirit of “Waste not, want not,” his skin is sometimes taken for grafting, and his hair for a wig. Exactly how many Falun Gong practitioners have been harvested is hard to determine, of course. The CCP goes to great lengths to cover up this barbarity. But Gutmann’s best guess is 65,000 — that is, 65,000 live harvests. [Source: The Slaughter: Mass Killings, Organ Harvesting, and China’s Secret Solution to Its Dissident Problem, by Ethan Gutmann](http://www.nationalreview.com/sites/default/files/nordlinger_gutmann08-25-14.html)

Comment: Are they killed specifically for the harvesting, or is the harvesting simply that "waste not want not" and they would have been killed anyway even if their organs weren't useful? Not that that changes much for the victims, of course.

Comment: @JAB, it is not being claimed that Falun Gong members are part of the Chinese society's ordinary organ-donation network.  The claim is a form of oppression directed at particular groups.